# Process one PublishSubject emission at a time with a chain of operators in RxJava2

Tags: rx-java2, sequential, publishsubject

I have a `PublishSubject<Event>`.

On each new *Event* I trigger a database query (some locally cached data), then take the result and try to *POST* it via *HTTP* request to a server, when this server replies *200* I make another database query to delete the rows that were just sent.

This is done with chaining roughly as so:

```
subject
  .toSerialized()
  .flatMapMaybe { getCachedData() }
  .flatMap { uploadData() }
  .flatMapCompletable { cleanCache() }
  .subscribe()
```

The *subject* may emit two quick *Events* under certain conditions, let's say with a 10 ms interval.

**The problem** is *getCachedData()* for the second emission goes off immediately after *getCachedData()* for the first emission completed, i.e. before *cleanCache()* had a chance to clean the database before second emission.

I would like to combine those *flatMaps* into one observer somehow so that the *subject* does no new emissions until the whole chain has finished, preferably without any kind of handmade semaphores.

I do *subscribeOn()* on a single thread pool scheduler, that only orders the calls inside each *flatMap*.

I saw some advice to add *toSerialized()* to subjects, but now I think it has no relation to the way chains work.

I saw there are also *lift()* and *compose()* operators. I tried to just put all *flatMaps* inside the latter, that did not change the behavior. The former I am still wondering about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them inside a `concatMapX` subflow:

```
subject
.concatMapCompletable {
    getCachedData()
    .flatMap { uploadData() }
    .flatMapCompletable { cleanCache() }
}
```

> I saw some advice to add toSerialized() to subjects, but now I think it has no relation to the way chains work

It has no practical effect on your flow unless you actually drive the `Subject` returned by it and from multiple threads.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much.